# How to melt with data.table into person years getting year suffix as variable column?

Tags: r, data.table, reshape

I have a data.table that looks like:

```
      PID  vara90  vara91  vara92 vara93 varb90  varb91  varb92 varb93
1:    1    2       1       45     77     "Str1"  "Str3"  "Str3" "Str1"
2:    2    6       1       5      3      "Str2"  "Str5"  "Str4" "Str1"
3:    3    1       1       56     65     "Str3"  "Str2"  "Str6" "Str1"
4:    4    8       1       45     9      "Str1"  "Str8"  "Str3" "Str2"
5:    5    12      3       45     44     "Str4"  "Str1"  "Str8" "Str3"
6:    6    2       6       78     1      "Str5"  "Str3"  "Str1" "Str4"
7:    7    2       3       45     23     "Str2"  "Str1"  "Str3" "Str1"
8:    8    2       1       44     87     "Str1"  "Str3"  "Str1" "Str4"
```

And want to get it into long format with the following shape:

```
      PID  year  vara      varb
1:    1    90       2       "Str1"  
2:    1    91       1       "Str3"
3:    1    92       45      "Str3"
.
.
.
```

I am using:

```
melt(df, id.vars("PID", measure=patterns("^vara","^varb"), value.name=c("vara","varb"),variable.name="year)
```

This gets me what I want, except that the `year` column is populated by numbers from 1 to 3. Is there a way to get the year column populated by the year suffixes from the variable names? I can do that with base `reshape` and with `tidyr`, but I have a really large dataset that asks for the memory efficiency of data.table.

Comment: A feature request for this was posted a couple months ago, currently set as a low priority https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1547 In the mean-time, you may simply need to parse the column names manually and assign the correct values after melting.

Comment: I see. Is there any documentation on how the numerical values for the `variable` column are set? Can I safely assume that they stand for the year stubs from low to high?

Comment: Good question. I think they are taken in the order of the columns (from left to right), but don't have docs to back it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until the FR linked by Frank is implemented, we'll have to set the levels manually (`variable` col is *factor*):

```
ans = melt(dt, measure = patterns("^vara", "^varb"),
              value.name = c("vara", "varb"), variable.name = "year")
setattr(ans$year, 'levels', gsub("vara", "", names(dt)[2:5]))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to melt two columns (var and year) from wide to long format.  The var and year information are combined in each column name.
I usually perform a combination of `gather %>% separate %>% spread` for these types of tasks.

The solution addresses your question about melting by actual year (instead of an index number), but I don't know if it has the performance efficiency of data.table.

The `separate(..., sep)` argument can be a regular expression or integer string position.

```
library(tidyr)
df1 <- gather(data=df, key=var.yr, value=temporaryValue, -PID)
df1 <- separate(data=df1, col=var.yr, into=c("var", "yr"), sep=4)
df1 <- spread(data=df1, key=var, value=temporaryValue)

head(df1)
#  PID yr vara varb
#1   1 90    2 Str1
#2   1 91    1 Str3
#3   1 92   45 Str3
#4   1 93   77 Str1
#5   2 90    6 Str2
#6   2 91    1 Str5
```

Comment: This is very inefficient. See [my UseR'15 talk, section Reshaping](http://user2015.math.aau.dk/presentations/93.pdf), or the [Efficient reshaping using data tables vignette](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).

Comment: Thanks for the resources!  Wow- `tidyr` is ~200 slower.  I didn't even know about the new `melt` too.  Guess I'll have to switch to data.table....