# Using melt with data.table only works with multiple measure variables

Tags: r, data.table, reshape, melt

I'm confused by the behavior of `data.table::melt()`.

I would like to reshape a data.table from wide to long, [similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36605445/how-to-melt-with-data-table-into-person-years-getting-year-suffix-as-variable-co)

Here's my data.table:

```
dt <- data.table(id=c(1,2,3), varA1=c(2,6,1), varA2=c(1,1,1),varA3=c(1,2,3),  
                              varB1=c(1,0,1), varB2=c(1,1,1),varB3=c(0,0,0))
```

Here's what I want:

```
  id index varA
1:  1     1    2
2:  2     1    6
3:  3     1    1 
4:  1     2    1
5:  2     2    1
6:  3     2    1
7:  1     3    1
8:  2     3    2
9:  3     3    3
```

If I include both `varA` and `varB` as my measure vars, it works fine, using:

`dt_long <- melt(dt, id.vars = "id", measure=patterns("^varA","^varB"), value.name = c("varA","varB"),variable.name = "index")`

The output is as expected:

```
   id index varA varB
1:  1     1    2    1
2:  2     1    6    0
3:  3     1    1    1
4:  1     2    1    1
5:  2     2    1    1
6:  3     2    1    1
7:  1     3    1    0
8:  2     3    2    0
9:  3     3    3    0
```

**However**, I only want `varA`. With only a single measure variable, it no longer works. Using

`dt_long <- melt(dt, id.vars ="id", measure=patterns("^varA"), value.name =  "varA",variable.name = "index")`

I get:

```
   id index varA
1:  1 varA1    2
2:  2 varA1    6
3:  3 varA1    1
4:  1 varA2    1
5:  2 varA2    1
6:  3 varA2    1
7:  1 varA3    1
8:  2 varA3    2
9:  3 varA3    3
```

Why is the `index` variable here not listing 1,2,3, as before?

Comment: See Ronak's comment below, if you agree, edit your question, then we can re-open it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using multiple columns with `melt` `measure.vars` is tricky.

From `melt` help regarding `measure.vars`:

> multiple patterns will produce multiple columns

If we apply `data.table:::patterns` source code to `dt` with `"^varA","^varB"`, we get :

```
cols <- colnames(dt)
p = unlist(list("^varA","^varB"), use.names = any(nzchar(list("^varA","^varB"))))
lapply(p, grep, cols)

[[1]]
[1] 2 3 4

[[2]]
[1] 5 6 7
```

Leading to :

- `VarA1` associated with `VarB1`, factor index = 1
- `VarA2` associated with `VarB2`, factor index = 2
- `VarA3` associated with `VarB3`, factor index = 3

Note that index number has nothing to do with VarXi index, it's simply an auto-numbering of `VarAi-VarBi` factor.

For example, if we remove `VarA1` we get following result:

```
   id index varA varB
1:  1     1    1    1
2:  2     1    1    0
3:  3     1    1    1
4:  1     2    1    1
5:  2     2    2    1
6:  3     2    3    1
7:  1     3   NA    0
8:  2     3   NA    0
9:  3     3   NA    0
```

- `VarA2` associated with `VarB1`, factor index = 1
- `VarA3` associated with `VarB2`, factor index = 2
- `VarB3` alone, factor index = 3

In both cases, as this factor is a composite factor, `data.table` returns its `numeric` index.

When you only use one `pattern`, you directly get a factor with `levels` corresponding to this single `pattern`:

```
dt_long <- melt(dt, id.vars = "id", measure=patterns("^varA"), value.name = c("varA"),variable.name = "index")[]
dt_long$index
[1] varA1 varA1 varA1 varA2 varA2 varA2 varA3 varA3 varA3
Levels: varA1 varA2 varA3
```

You could convert it to `numeric` to get the expected result:

```
dt_long[,index :=as.numeric(index)][]
   id index varA
1:  1     1    2
2:  2     1    6
3:  3     1    1
4:  1     2    1
5:  2     2    1
6:  3     2    1
7:  1     3    1
8:  2     3    2
9:  3     3    3
```